# How to change the design of a certain ng-select through id using CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, angular-ngselect

```
 <ng-select id="province" (keyup)="this.userData.onKeyUp3($event)" [ngModel]="selectedOneSubDistrict3" (ngModelChange)="onChangez3($event)" formControlName="province3">
                                    <ng-option *ngFor="let item of this.userData.residenceList "[value]="item.residenceList+'/'+item.regionId">{{item.residenceList}}</ng-option>
                                  </ng-select>
```

how to edit the css to change the width of the ng-select with the id="province"

Comment: a css rule like `#province{ width: /*anything*/; }` ?

Comment: it doesn't change the containers width https://imgur.com/a/oulLiLv

Comment: try use the `!important` in css rule ?  Or you can provide more information for help

Comment: .ng-select .ng-select-container {
    min-height: 24px !important;
    min-width: 900px !important;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;

  } this worked but i want to access only the province ng-select not all of the ng-select

Answer (score 0):

to change ng-select try this :

```
.ng-select#province {
    border:0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

let me know if you need more informations or explication

Answer (score 0):

```css
#province .ng-select-container {
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

this solved it for me